# Sorting the contact by VCard's categories

Tags: contacts, vcard

My contacts are currently stored on a CardDav server (more specifically, an OwnCloud instance) and I am using DAVDroid to do the synchronization. 
The problem I have is that I want to be the VCard categories to be used to sort and filter my contacts, a little like the groups of the default contact app, and the default Contacts apps does not seems to allow that. Also, moving my contacts to gmail storing to use the group feature instead is not really an option.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)

Comment: In fact, I gave a lot of thought to this question. My question is more of "how can I have my contacts sorted by categories ?", but given that the response will be "you cannot on the default contact app and need to install a custom contact application", I thought going to the next step directly was for the best :)

Comment: I can follow your thinking, but that's not how this site works (please see our [help/on-topic] for details). Your phrasing clearly indicates asking for app recommendations. Rather describe the problem you're trying to solve: while *explicitly asking* for app recommendations is off-topic here, answers might include such.

Comment: This seems like a valid issue. Leaving this open.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Contacts
2. Menu -> contacts to display
3. Choose Customize
4. Choose your email or G+ account
5. Select that groups to show
6. Hit OK and all the individuals with those labels will be shown

Source: Tested on Contacts app running on a KK 4.4

Comment: It's only working if your contact are stored on your Gmail account, it's seems. My contact account is a DAVDroid account, the only choice I have is "All contacts".